# TEXTVIEW авто размер текста

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

Предположим что у textview высота+ширина 50 процентов от родителя. Как сделать чтобы по дефолту размер текста занимал полностью данную ему область.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Просто в XML файле подогнать размер под нужный и он будет дефолтный , если имеете ввиду единицы измерения , то sp - независимая от размера экрана величина(подгоняет под экран). А так конкретики бы и примеров

Comment: Как размер текста может что-то занимать?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы размер текста подстраивался под ширину и высоту. Т.е при 100x100 ширины и длины был к примеру 15sp, а 200x200 30sp, по типу такого.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Comment: а есть какой либо способ или библиотека которая минимум 18 API поддерживает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**До 26 API**

```
app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12dp"
app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50dp"
```

**После 26 API**

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```